# Magento 2 and Tax US

Tags: magento-2.1, import, tax

Has anybody used any extension for a US eshop to import the various TAX automatically?

I had accurateTax for Magento 1, but they don't support M2. What is the best option for Magento 2.1.4?

Answer (score 0):

[TaxJar](https://www.taxjar.com) and [Vertex](https://www.vertexinc.com/) are both premier Magento technology partners with M2 sales tax extensions.

Speaking on behalf of TaxJar, we have a backup rates feature allowing you to import tax rates automatically (based on where you have [nexus](https://blog.taxjar.com/sales-tax-nexus-definition/)) and keep them up-to-date via monthly cron jobs.

- [TaxJar Magento 2 Extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/taxjar-module-taxjar.html) ([GitHub](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento2-extension))
- [TaxJar Magento 2 Extension Guide](https://www.taxjar.com/guides/integrations/magento2/)

Comment: can you please help me with this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843516/taxjar-returns-0-for-all-states-except-nexus-address-state